# Best way to parse Java in Java

Tags: java, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

As the title says, I want to parse some Java source code in Java. I'm pretty sure there are other java libraries that already perform this, but I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Janino](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JANINO/Home) can parse, compile and execute Java code.

Comment: Awesome! I really didn't want to use generic parser-generators for this, because the tokens are probably more fine-grained then what I want.

Comment: @Jeeyoung Kim, be sure to read the `Limitations` section: most Java 5 (and up) features are not supported.

Answer (score 6):

Antlr has a grammar file for Java. See [this](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/list).

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking for something like ANTLR: http://www.antlr.org/

Comment: I didn't, but there should be a tool or library or something. You don't want to have to hack together the Java grammar.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse exposes the Syntax Tree of it's own Java compiler. You can simply access the elements.

See [here](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-JavaCodeManipulation_AST/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

JavaCC has a Java 1.5 grammar including generics.

> the tokens are probably more
>   fine-grained then what I want

Your first requirement is to get an accurate parse, and you will realistically only get that from an existing parser. What you do with the result is up to you.