# java bytecode manipulate; insert Print code after every java code

Tags: java

I want to insert Print code after every java code.
For example:

```
public void  myMethod() {
   Integer i = 0;
   Long l = 0L;
   Date date = new Date();
}
```

to:

```
public void  myMethod() {
   Integer i = 0;
   System.out.println("test");
   Long l = 0L;
   System.out.println("test");
   Date date = new Date();
   System.out.println("test");
}
```

how should I do?Can you help me?

Comment: You've just did that.

Comment: @MarounMaroun nope. He want to insert that through byte code.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ I don't really understand what's the meaning of inserting print statement to the bytecode :/

Comment: Better use a step by step debugger.

Comment: @MarounMaroun logging? but it should not be static in this case

Comment: You mean to  insert automatically

Comment: @MarounMaroun http://asm.ow2.org/

Comment: Printing a fixed string after every line seems kind of pointless, what are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes,I want use java bytecode library manipulate java bytecode to insert my java code automatically.And I have learn the ASM,but I don't find how I to do.It seem ASM can't manipulate java classes line by line.

Comment: One problem is you cannot identify the boundary easily between each statement in the byte code.

Comment: Some context still might help. What code do you want to insert and to what end? What is your goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to a solution in the compiler

1 parse your code:

[Best way to parse Java in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763091/best-way-to-parse-java-in-java)

2 insert automatically code:

use JET for example

https://eclipse.org/articles/Article-JET2/jet_tutorial2.html

SECOND SOLUTION

create and put some annotation (by hand)

RUNTIME SOLUTION

you have to investigate bytecode.

Some links:
http://web.cs.ucla.edu/~msb/cs239-tutorial/

see the chapter: Generating Call Traces

And posts around this tag:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-bytecode-asm

Comment: At first,thank you for your answer.And I have a question,what do you think of using a bytecode library like ASM to do this?Can it work?

Comment: @GanZhang , Yes, it could,  I put some links: see the link on UCLA.